# Is this particular take on the Serenity Prayer grammatically correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I wish to know the correct translation of this more empowered and secular version of the Serenity Prayer:

> Let me have the serenity to accept the things I cannot change,
> courage to change the things I can,
> and wisdom to know the difference.

> Da mihi serenitatem accipere quae non possum mutare,
> animos mutare res quae possum,
> atque sapientiam differentiam cognoscere.

Is this right? Thank you in advance!

PS: It's for a tattoo, hence the extra need for scrutiny

Edit: I'm aware that there's a similar thread, but for me it's important that it's not "God grant me" but "Let me have", as I wish to have this power from within and not relying on external factors.

Edit2: Removed the "res" before "quae"

Edit3: I've had it translated by a professional translator and she came up with:

> Habeam aequum animum ut quae mutare non possim feram
> ac fortitudinem ut quae mutare possim mutem
> ac sapientiam ut haec ab illis discernam

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/latin-translation-for-the-serenity-prayer

Comment: As @SebastianKoppehel noted, there is already a question on this. The extra caution on tattoos isn't unwarranted, though, so if you like, if you have further questions that the other thread doesn't answer or **desire a more specific answer to your translation**, feel free to edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: For what it's worth, the translation you provided is a fairly straightforward translation and is mostly grammatically correct, with just a few quibbles (no *res*!).

Comment: @cmw I definitely wouldn't want those infinitives on my skin. By the way, the source of this translation appears to be the [back cover](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41NHVyk6UkL.jpg) of Neil Young's 1981 album "Re-ac-tor." (With *fortitudinem* instead of *animos*, which is another one of those quibbles …)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel That actually makes it easier for inking - if anyone doubts the translation, just blame Neil Young! And you're right that the infinitives are an Anglicism, whereas Latin would likely have a purpose clause.

Comment: @cmw Not classical, certainly, but aren't infinitives of purpose fairly common in later (especially church) Latin?

Comment: @Draconis♦: They might also be used in classical poetry, but even there they are exceptional (probably Graecisms?).

Comment: @Draconis [I do think there's something to that!](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/when-did-the-infinitive-of-purpose-arise) I guess since this is not a prayer and isn't necessarily looking at classical Latin, the [prohibition on the infinitive of purpose](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/purpose-clauses) isn't warranted.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I'm aware of that thread, but the key issue being that his starts with "God grant me". The reason (if you're interested) I prefer it like this is because I wouldn't want to rely on any outside factors, I wish for myself to have this strength from within.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel would you please elaborate on the infinitives?

Comment: @cmw so basically just remove the "res" and it's proper Latin?

Comment: @ReinierWijnen I'll let others chime in on the Medieval/Late Latin use of the infinitive of purpose, but res isn't correct here.

Comment: I also altered the title to better reflect what you're actually looking for, I think. Let me know if you have any questions or problems with that or feel free to continue revising until it suits your needs.

Comment: @cmw thank you, hopefully people who are familiar with (Classical) Latin will be so kind to confirm proper grammar.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is this, since all three of the qualities that the prayer refers to can by expressed through adjectives that modify *animus* in Latin:

> *animo sim satis aequo ut ea patiar quae mutare nequeam, satis forti ut ea mutem quae mutare queam, satis sapienti ut haec ab illis discernam.*

> May I be of a mind that is sufficiently level that I accept those things that I'm unable to change, sufficiently brave that I change those things that I'm able to change, sufficiently sensible that I distinguish the latter from the former.

Answer (score 3):

*Da mihi serenitatem accipere* sounds to me like "Grant me to accept serenity", which is not what you want to say.

In this case, I'd go with the subjunctive, something like *Da mihi serenitatem ut accipiam quae non possum mutare, animum ut mutem quae possum, atque sapientiam ut cognoscam quid distet.*

EDIT: I originally used *utrum intersit* instead of *quid distet* but wasn't sure it was quite right. After doing a corpus search on PHI, I feel quite confident that *quid distet* will work, but I don't have the same level of confidence in *utrum intersit*, or *utrum referat*.

Comment: Since the asker specifically wants to not have an external force granting the various aspects, _dā_ seems strange.

Comment: @Draconis I don't know about strange, but perhaps unnecessary. I'm in the middle of concocting a translation which drops the imperative, which I'll post shortly as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to translate this. If you go the route of using a subjunctive, you can drop the imperative *da* entirely. Also you can use gerundives instead of infinitives of purpose.

*Habeam serenitatem ad accipienda quae mutare non possum, animum ad mutanda quae possum, et sapientiam ad cognoscendum quid distet*.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is what I ended up going with, a more poetic version:

"Dona mihi animi aequitatem, ut quae mutare non possim, clementer feram; ac fortitudinem, ut quae mutare possim, mutem; ac sapientiam, ut haec ab illis discernam."

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but it looks like the artist put *mature* instead of *mutare* in the fourth line.

Comment: On the plus side, at least mature is an actual Latin word, so some sense can still be made of what's there: 'and the courage to change what I'm able [to change] in plenty of time.'

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible ways to translate a thing like this like the other answers indicate.
Let me just discuss the translation you offer in your latest update:

> Habeam aequum animum ut quae mutare non possim feram
> ac fortitudinem ut quae mutare possim mutem
> ac sapientiam ut haec ab illis discernam

The use of *habeam* works great:
it is a wish to have the power, not for anyone to give it to you, and the present tense implies possibility whereas the imperfect *haberem* would be an unachievable wish.

The flow of the text is natural and the structure clear.
I consider this to be in good style, and given the context you describe, I would prefer this to the offerings of the other answers.

The only thing that struck me as somewhat weird is using *ferre* for "accept".
This verb has a wildly broad range of possible meanings, and "to suffer, tolerate, endure" is indeed among them.
See part II.B.5 of [the entry in Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=fero&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
The many other meanings, like "carry, show, report, celebrate, conduct, flow, take away, produce, receive", may lead the reader astray.
If this is an ambiguity you want to avoid, then a more narrow Latin verb would be in order.
The best alternative that comes to mind is [*tolerare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=tolero&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), so my only suggestion is to consider changing *feram* to *tolerem*.
The verb *ferre* strikes me as stylistically more suitable, but it is more open to misinterpretation — the choice is yours.

Comment: Agree that this is an excellent translation. I'd actually vote for *feram* over alternatives like *tolerem*, since *fero* is the most basic/common Latin verb for this meaning; ambiguity doesn't seem like a big problem here given that the meaning is clear from context and that this is a well-known quote (not to mention that such lexical ambiguity is very common in real Latin texts).

Comment: @TKR I agree that *feram* is the most stylish choice and what a Roman author would have been likely to choose. I just wanted to point the potential ambiguity out explicitly so that the OP can judge whether it is fine. The context reduces the room for misinterpretation quite a bit here. It's very true that tolerance for ambiguity is often needed with Latin.